# Export SQL result to Excel by using OPENROWSET, but provider has not been registered

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, oledb

I tried to export the sql result to Excel by using below queries:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=c:\Test.xls;','SELECT client_name, Client_number FROM dbo.Client')
select * from dbo.client
```

However I got this error:

```
Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" has not been registered.
```

After I searched about workaround and downloaded the 2010 Microsoft Office System file "Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable", it still give me the same error when I run the query above. I changed the provider's name to "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" and run below queries again:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\Test.xls;','SELECT client_name, Client_number FROM dbo.Client')
select * from dbo.client
```

It still give me this error:

```
Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here please?

Comment: Possibly an issue of the 64 bit vs 32 bit version of the access database engine. Try the 64 bit driver and see?

Comment: The one I just installed was already for fixing this 64-bit incompatibility issue, which should work and worked for most people who's in 64-bit. No idea why it doesn't work on my station@JacobH

Comment: 1) Do you have x64 or x32 version of SQL Server? I mean **SQL Server**, not your OS      2) Are you sure you installed Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable successfully?

Comment: @sepupic It's x64 version SQL, I checked with "select @@version". I think it is installed successfully cuz it was run by the IT support guy. We are not allowed to install anything on our workstation by ourselves though

Comment: The driver should be install not on your workstation, but on the server

Comment: When you get the driver problem sorted you should watch where the spreadsheet is located. The c:\Test.xls in you example refers to the C: drive on your server and NOT on your workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to summarize:

In order to use OPENROWSET for export/import excel files from/to x64 SQL Server you should install Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable on your server, not on your workstation. Until you successfully install this x64 bit driver on your server pc you'll get the error

```
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered
```

while trying to use this provider in your OPENROWSET queries

Answer (score 0):

This works for 16.0 or 12.0 as follows..
Open SSMS as Administrator, it won't work otherwise.

Run

```
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop
```

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 should be there.
Run if AllowInProcess and DynamicParameters in results above are not 1.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0'

, N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0'

, N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO


EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Then try: (Make sure the spreadsheet is closed!)

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=c:\test.xls;','SELECT Column1 FROM [ExcelSheet$]')
select Column1 from dbo.SQLTable
```

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 can be obtained from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

The above also works with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=c:\test.xls;','SELECT Column1 FROM [ExcelSheet$]')
select Column1 from dbo.SQLTable
```

In which case

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255 is needed.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'

, N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
, N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

You can replace Excel 12.0 with Excel 8.0 above.